# Is there a Way to get all documents by Search in Java by neglecting DocReader field

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus, xpages-ssjs

Is there a Way to get all documents by Search in Java by neglecting DocReader field 
I am trying to get all the documents but it only gives me the list of document to which I am docreader. Is there any way to bypass the DocReader field.

Comment: Is this in a java agent or via Xpages?  If it is xpages, look at the OpenNTF Domino API as it has `SessionFullAccess` that may be of use.

Comment: A Best Practice for the implementation of Readers fields is to include an administrative role such as "[All_Access]" that assures that all docs can be accessed by someone (and/or servers). If this has NOT been done then the Full Access Admin is the only work around.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but you need to be [granted Full Access Administration rights](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSKTMJ_8.5.3/com.ibm.help.domino.admin85.doc/H_RESTRICTING_ADMINISTRATOR_ACCESS_4559_STEPS.html) in the Server document in the Domino Directory. Then you need to [enable full access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357775/full-access-administration-mode-for-lotus-notes) for the Java code that you are running. (Note that the previous link goes to a StackOverflow question dealing with Java accessing Domino via DIIOP, which is problematic - but the answers cover the overall topic pretty well.)

Comment: And I would further clarify Richard's answer to say that you have to be listed in the Allow Full Administrative Rights field on the server document as well.

Comment: That's what my first sentence says, and the first link describes. :-)

Comment: Oops, you're right.  Sorry about that!  Now he really knows.

Comment: I'll point out one more thing though: If you can't get Full Access Admin privileges for yourself, the other alternative is to have someone else who has Full Access Admin rights sign your code.